# How to navigate past the popup ad using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to navigate through oddschecker website using selenium in python with chrome webdriver but an add comes up. See image:

[image]

Is there a line of code I can use to get rid of the ad and access the site without having to click on the cross in top right corner manually?

Code trials:

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
mylink = 'https://www.oddschecker.com'
driver.get(mylink)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate past the popup ad the only way is to click and close the popup ad element *inducing WebDriverWait* for the *`element_to_be_clickable()`* and you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
  # click and close the cookie banner
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='CookieBannerAcceptButton']"))).click()
  # click and close the popup ad
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close Offers Modal'][class^='CloseButtonDesktop']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
  # click and close the cookie banner
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='OK']"))).click()
  # click and close the popup ad
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close Offers Modal' and starts-with(@class, 'CloseButtonDesktop')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this however it no longer seems to work, is it possible the host changed the tags of the buttons? How do I view and locate them? Whenever I inspect it vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

This would help you in closing the ad.

```
driver.get('https://www.oddschecker.com')
time.sleep(4)    
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-label='Close Offers Modal']").click()
```

P.S. I wrote in python. If you are writing in some other language, you may transform this line per the syntax of your language.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate AdBlocker extension within you chrome driver just like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('load-extension=' + EXTENSION_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.create_options()
```